# How to check if JSON keys have particular word using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
  "workbookInformation" : { … },
  "datasources4" : { … },
  "datasources5" : { … },
  "datasources2" : { … },
  "datasources3" : { … },
  "datasources1" : { … }
}
```

In my case, I need to fetch number of object whose keys have `datasource` keyword.

Comment: Look at Object.keys(yourobject)

Comment: `Object.keys(yourobject).filter(x => x.includes('datasource')).length` should work

Comment: @Satpal `Object.keys(yourobject).filter(x => x.includes('datasource'))` ES6 code will not work in IE9

Comment: The JSON needs to be parsed first, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ES6 version.

```
var keys = Object.keys(yourobject).filter(x => x.includes('datasource'));
```

ES5

```
var keys = Object.keys(yourobject).filter(function (x) {
    return x.includes('datasource');
});
```

If you want to check the keys starts with the term use `x.startsWith('datasource')` or `x.indexOf("datasource")==0`.

```js
var yourobject = {
  "datasource1": {},
  "datasource2": {},
  "datasource3": {},
  "datasource5": {},
  "datasource4": {},
  "data": {},
  "source": {}
}
console.log(Object.keys(yourobject).filter(x => x.includes('datasource')).length);
```

Comment: indexOf won't work because keyword can occur anywhere in the key. He did not mention that keyword should be at the start of key string.

Comment: I will elaborate: Or `indexOf("datasource")==0` if you are looking for keys starting with datasource - This is likely the case since his key started with datasource and he did not specify "contain" but "have"

Comment: @mplungjan, Agreed in this case I prefer [`startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

Comment: Even better since you are using ES6 anyway. I stand corrected

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = {
"datasource1":{},
"datasource2":{},
"datasource3":{},
"datasource5":{},
"datasource4":{},
"data":{},
"source":{}
}
for(var key in a){
  if(key.indexOf('datasource') > -1){ // or ==0 if "starts with"
    console.log('I have datasource');
  }
}
```

Comment: @mplungjan, what if the key doesn't start with *datasource*? OP's question asked for checking if key starts with certain word, but the body was drifted away from the title.

Comment: See my modification .